# Como verificar se um arquivo foi adicionado em um diretório em java?

Tags: java, arquivo, diretório

Preciso que um programa em Java, verifique se em um diretório foi adicionado algum arquivo de texto. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Qualquer arquivo? Ele é seu! Precisa ficar escutando o diretório ou basta que confirme a escrita do arquivo!

Comment: Qualquer arquivo, poderia dar um exemplo de como escutar o diretório ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `WatchService` do pacote `java.nio.file`.

1. Criar o serviço:

   `WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();`
2. Registrar o caminho que será escutado. O registro tem que ser feito em uma classe que implementa `Watchable`. Você pode utilizar a classe `Path` do `java.nio.file`.

`//Diretório que será verificado se o arquivo foi criado`

`Path diretorio = Paths.get("C:\\stackoverflow");`

`//registra o serviço criado`

`diretorio.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);`

No método `register` você irá passar quais são os eventos que você está interessado, por exemplo, criação, remoção ou alteração. No seu caso você só está preocupado com a criação, por isso apenas o `ENTRY_CREATE` está sendo passado como parâmetro. O método `register` também retorna uma `WatchKey` que representa o registro realizado.

3. Será necessário criar um loop infinito que irá capturar os eventos de interesse que ocorrem no diretório e verificar se o arquivo possui a extensão desejada.
4. Os eventos que ocorrem no diretório são enfileirados na `WatchKey` que por sua vez pode ser acessada pelo `WatchService`. O método `take` irá retornar uma `WatchKey` onde ocorreu algum evento de interesse.

`WatchKey key = watcher.take();`

5. Através do método `pollEvents` é possível acessar os eventos que ocorreram na `WatchKey`.

`Optional<WatchEvent<?>> watchEvent= key.pollEvents().stream().findFirst();`

Nesse caso, como só estamos escutando eventos de criação, não precisamos verificar o tipo do evento. Caso estivéssemos escutando mais de um evento, seria necessário também verificar o tipo do evento:

```
Optional<WatchEvent<?>> watchEvent= key.pollEvents().stream().filter(event -> event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE).findFirst();
```

6. O nome o arquivo pode ser pego através do método `context`:

`Path path = (Path) watchEvent.get().context();`

7. A extensão pode ser verificada utilizando a classe `FilenameUtils` do Apache Commons-IO:

`FilenameUtils.getExtension(path.toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("txt")`

8. Por fim, é necessário chamar o método `reset` na `WatchKey` para que novos eventos continuem sendo capturados. A `WatchKey` possui 3 estados: **ready**, **signaled** e **invalid**. A `WatchKey` apenas aceita novos eventos quando está no estado de **ready**. A `Watchkey` fica no estado de **ready** quando é criada e após a execução do método `reset`. Após aceitar um evento ela vai para o estado de **signaled**. Além desses dois estados ela pode ir para o estado **invalid** caso o registro da chave seja cancelado através da execução do método `cancel`, se o diretório ficar inacessível ou se o `WatchService` estiver fechado.
9. Além disso, é necessário verificar se o ocorreu o evento de `OVERFLOW`. Esse evento pode ser capturado apesar de não termos registrado nele. Isso pode acontecer caso o evento seja perdido ou descartado devido algum comportamento inesperado. Por causa disso ele precisa ser verificado para que não ocorra nenhum erro no código:

   `if  (watchEvent.get().kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {`
   `continue;`
   `}`

O código final fica dessa forma:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    //Diretório que será verificado se o arquivo foi criado
    Path diretorio = Paths.get("C:\\stackoverflow");
    //registra o serviço criado
    diretorio.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

    while (true) {
        WatchKey key = watcher.take();
        Optional<WatchEvent<?>> watchEvent= key.pollEvents().stream().findFirst();
        if (watchEvent.isPresent()) {
            if  (watchEvent.get().kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            Path path = (Path) watchEvent.get().context();
            //Verifica se o arquivo possui a extensão txt
            if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(path.toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) { 
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
    }

    watcher.close();
}
```